# How to open default camera in the app with all options in titanium?

Tags: ios, camera, titanium, titanium-modules

I am developing a application for iOS in Titanium that is related to the camera. I have used `Titanium.Media.showCamera` module for opening the  camera.

Unfortunately, it gives me only two options i.e. mediaTypes: `[Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO]`.

But I am looking for these options: `“SQUARE”,”TIME LAPSE”,”SLOW MOTION”,”PANO”`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that these functions are not covered by the Titanium API set for now. In the [documentation](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Camera+and+Photo+Gallery+APIs) none of these functions can be found. So the only way to integrate these functions is using modules.

**Squared images**

[SquareCamera Module](https://github.com/mikefogg/SquareCamera)
This should give you the possibility to create squared photos (and more). Although I have never used it you should give it a try. It also allows customizing your camera view, e.g. adjusting the picture quality.

Another module you could try out is [FilterableCamera](https://github.com/k0sukey/FilterableCamera-likeInstagramUI). I would try it only if you are not satisfied with SquareCamera since the documentation is kind of not existing which can be frustrating.

All other functions are not covered by modules yet. For `'Panorama'` I found the (still open) [Jira issue](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-11748). Maybe you can leave a comment there and ask the developers directly. Furthermore you should open new Jira issues for the implementation of the other functions.